# Informatica : Returning decimal data upon encountering a number

Tags: informatica

I have a scenario to store an incoming number in decimal format. And, the datatype of the port has to be a String.

Example : 
INPUT : String : 0 ;
OUTPUT : String : 0.00

INPUT : String : 182 ;
OUTPUT : String : 182.00

Had my output port datatype been a Decimal, this would have been easy to achieve. But, since it's a String,I'm unable to do so. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR(TO_DECIMAL(input_column,2))`

Answer (score 0):

In one of your transformations create a "output port" under your incoming input port. In the expression use:

```
To_Char(To_Decimal(i_columnName,2))
```

See photo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGebi.png

Answer (score 0):

Please use this Logic's it working for me.

```
   TO_CHAR(TO_DECIMAL(INPUT_PORT,2)).
```